# Negative critical exponent $\alpha$ for Superfluid helium at lambda point

Tags: phase-transition, critical-phenomena, superfluidity

Due to the positive critical exponent of the transition in liquid helium I would expect there to be no peak at the transition $t=0$. Since the $t$ dependent part of the specific heat should go to 0 as $C \approx A \,  t^{0.0127} + B$. What is going on here? Is this understood? It seems that the critical exponent $\alpha$ (defined by $C\sim t^{-\alpha}$) as fitted would be positive. Yet RG/Bootstrap predicts a negative value of $\alpha$.

Can the negative value of $\alpha$ be found by the experiment in any way? Or does its value just come from theoretical predictions?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient $A$ satisfies $A<0$. Also note that the background contribution $B$ is different for $T<T_c$ and $T>T_c$.

Comment: Great! So simple an answer. Should have realized it.