# Divergent or not? the heat capacity at the lambda point

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

In Kerson Huang's book (2nd edition, page 309), it is stated that at the lambda point, the heat capacity diverges logarithmically. But, in wiki, it is stated that it is finite.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_point

Which is right?

Answer (score 1):

Huang refers to an old experiment by Fairbank. Theory, as well as modern experiments (cited in the wikipedia article) suggest that the specific heat exponent $\alpha$ is small and negative. The specific heat is finite, but non-analytic. See also [this SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/587251/negative-critical-exponent-alpha-for-superfluid-helium-at-lambda-point/587454#587454).